# If statement won't print text

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input

username = raw_input("Enter Username : ")
password = raw_input("Enter Password : ")

if username == "bert" and password == "peter":
        print("Logged in")
```

and i want it to say `logged in` but it doesn't say anything. It just won't accept anything I'm doing, does anyone know the answer?

(started today so it can be a small fix)

EDIT: it should have been `input` instead of `raw_input`

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Just use `input`, not `raw_input`. (In Python 2, you don't need to import `raw_input`, it should already be there.) Your if statement looks fine.

Comment: Maybe something messed up the native `raw_input`. Remove the first line and try again.

Comment: wow, that was it. looiking up for 30 mins and its that -_- (had to be input alone)

Comment: Try printing the values of `username` and `password`. For example like `print("username = '{0}'".format(username))` (note the use of quotes around the string being printed, so you can easily see things like newlines).

Comment: My guess is that `raw_input` is including the `\n` character when you press Enter after entering the username/password. Thus your `if` statement is not matching because there is a trailing character after your username/password. You could use `if "bert" in username and "peter" in password`, but better still might be to strip the trailing characters: `if username.strip() == "bert" and password.strip() == "peter"`

Comment: Your module and shell encoding system  are different. (encode, decode ?)

Comment: @FluffyMe Take a look at the solution

Comment: @Engineero when you use raw_input(), it strips a trailing newline.

Comment: @s_vishnu ah, that makes sense. Never mind then.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your question, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, add an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to import anything.
Also raw_input was changed to input in Python 3.
So

Your_variable = `input("Enter input:")`

Would do good.

If you want to use raw_input functionality in Python 3 then use

`eval(input())`

Difference between them previously.

If you enter 5 to input
It takes the value, finds it type and stores it as an **integer**

```
A = input("Enter :")
```

Where as raw_input stored it as a **string**

This has changed now so simply use input.
And if you want to store anything as an integer . Just use this.

`a = int(input("Enter value: "))`

Answer (score 0):

raw_input is a built-in function, you don't need to import anything. Just delete the first line and run it again.